# Making a stand-alone image with gastex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, document-classes

I want to do the following:

1. Make an image using `gastex`.
2. Compile the image to a stand-alone pdf image. I.e., at the end of this stage I'll have a `myImage.pdf` file.
3. Include my image in a large latex file.

The idea is that I like working with `gastex` but I want to compile my latex file with `pdflatex`. (I know there is a new feature of compiling `gastex` with `pdflatex` but I can't make it work so I prefer going this way.)

The problem with step (2) is that I don't know what should be the `documentclass` I should use. E.g., using `\documentclass{article}` produces a A4 page with the image on it. I want the file to contain only the image. Also, maybe there a way to do this with `\documentclass{article}` and with playing with the page sizes?

For some reason `standalone` doesn't work for me. This code passes `latex` but `dvipdf` crashes on it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{gastex}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(100,10)(0,0)
\setlength{\unitlength}{3.5pt}
\gasset{Nw=5,Nh=5} %nWidth nHeight
\node[Nmarks=i,iangle=90](A1)(5,0){$s_1$}
\node(A2)(15,0){$s_2$}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A first attempt should be with the `standalone` class. Can you give a simple example of a picture file?

Comment: You *can't* use `dvipdfm` with `gastex`, only `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`

Comment: I usually compile with `latex`+`dvipdf` and it works. Using `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` doesn't work on this code as well. (Fails in the last step)

Comment: If the problems with `standalone` persist, you could always use `article` (don't forget `\pagestyle{empty}`) and postprocess with `pdfcrop`.

Comment: This is a good solution. Do you want to post it as an answer so you could get credit?

Comment: I'd rather wait a little. If the problems with `standalone` can be sorted out, that would be much preferrable...

Comment: Have you checked you're using the latest version of `standalone`?

Answer (score 2):

With this input file `guy.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{gastex}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(200,200)(-100,-100)
\setlength{\unitlength}{3.5pt}
\gasset{Nw=5,Nh=5} %nWidth nHeight
\node[Nmarks=i,iangle=90](A1)(5,0){$s_1$}
\node(A2)(15,0){$s_2$}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

and the command line

```
simpdftex latex guy && pdfcrop guy.pdf
```

(`simpdftex` just uses `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`) I get the following `guy-crop.pdf`

[image]

With the command line

```
latex guy && dvipdf guy && pdfcrop guy.pdf
```

the output is similar (but wrong):

[image]

Notice the arrow tip. The `(200,200)(-100,100)` coordinates for `picture` are just for being sure the bounding box will contain the picture, so `pdfcrop` will find the right boundaries. It seems that `gastex` doesn't advertise the bounding box of what it's producing.

However, the page http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/gastex/index.php tells that version 2.9b6 (not on TeX Live) works with `auto-pst-pdf` and so is "compatible" with `pdflatex`.

Comment: `simpdftex latex guy` is failing for me. I get `Error: /undefined in !BP`, `GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`, and a stack trace. Can I supply any other information that might help?

Comment: @Guy Operating system and TeX distribution?

Comment: @Guy It doesn't work with `standalone` in TeX Live 2009 and 2010, unfortunately. Probably the `article` method is the way to go with such an old system.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. And: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`. So, it shouldn't work...

Comment: @Guy The Ubuntu provided TeX Live is irremediably outdated.

Comment: @Guy: The v0.x `standalone` uses `preview` by default which seems cause the issue. The v1.x `crop` option however works. I heavily recommend you to install TeX Live yourself. See [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)